# "ERROR: Invalid requirement: pip3 install torch==1.5.0+cpu torchvision==0.6.0+cpu -f", while deployment

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, pytorch, torch

I'm deploying a application on Heroku and that application needs Torch module to install on the server and I'm unable to push the app using git because of this error....
I tried many methods but unable to push it...
Tell me what should I write in the requirements.txt in order to install torch

Comment: you tried to put in your requirements.txt the missing files ? and you checked if the file is in the right format ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the url of wheel file (from [torch_stable.html](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html)) of torch (and torchvision, if required) corresponding to the required version in your `requirements.txt` file. Then, `pip` will install the wheel file.

e.g.

```
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.5.0%2Bcpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

The above file corresponds to pytorch (cpu) 1.5, python 3.7, linux.